# How do the compareTo and equals methods work in this example?

Tags: java

I do not understand the `compareTo()` method and `equals()` method. How do they work in the code below? Please describe it for me, and look at my comments under the methods.

I do not understand how it prints out the patients ordered according to the `prio` for each patient. Help would be appreciated.

```
 import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class Patient implements Comparable<Patient>  {
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String personNbr;
    private int prio;
    private int number;
    private static int total = 0;

    public Patient(String firstname, String lastname, String personNbr, int prio) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.personNbr = personNbr;
        this.prio = prio;
        total++;
        number = total;

    }

    public int compareTo(Patient rhs) {
        if(prio==rhs.prio) {
            return number - rhs.number; // what happens here?
        } else {
            return prio - rhs.prio; // what happens here?
        }
        }

    public boolean equals(Object rhs) {
        if (rhs instanceof Patient) {  // what happens here?
        return compareTo((Patient) rhs) == 0; // what happens here?
        } else {
        return false;
        }
        }

    public String toString() {
        return this.firstname + this.lastname + this.personNbr + this.prio;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PriorityQueue<Patient> pq = new PriorityQueue<Patient>();
        pq.offer(new Patient("Kalle", "Karlsson", "8503622-1213", 3));
        pq.offer(new Patient("Lisa", "Svensson", "840312-1224", 7));
        pq.offer(new Patient("Lena", "Nilsson", "820323-1224", 9));
        pq.offer(new Patient("Kallee", "Karlssonn", "85503622-1213", 3));

        System.out.println(pq.toString());
    }

    }
```

the output is

```
[KalleKarlsson8503622-12133, KalleeKarlssonn85503622-12133, LenaNilsson820323-12249, LisaSvensson840312-12247]
```

Comment: Did you read the javadoc for [compareTo()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and [equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`equals()` method is used to compare the two instances of the class for equality. It comes from `Object` class of java. All the class in the java have equals() method available for comparison. You can always provide custom implementation according to the class member and equality definition.

The `compareTo()` is used primary by Collections framework for sorting the array or ordering the elements in a priority queue. `compareTo()` comes from `Comparable` interface.

---

```
public int compareTo(Patient rhs) {
    if(prio==rhs.prio) {
        return number - rhs.number; // First line
    } else {
        return prio - rhs.prio; // Second line
    }
 }
```

The `compareTo()` method is defined on the basis of `number` and `prio` attributes of the class. The `compareTo()` return negative, zero or positive when current instance is smaller then passed, equal or grater respectively.

---

```
public boolean equals(Object rhs) {
    if (rhs instanceof Patient) {  // First Line
      return compareTo((Patient) rhs) == 0; // Second Line
    } else {
      return false;
    }
 }
```

In the first line, you are checking that argument passed to method is instance of `Patient` class. Because you are checking the equality of two instance which should be of same type.

Second line, You are using the `compareTo()` method to define the equality of the instances.

---

Update in the question:

Here is the `toString()` method.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return
      "firstname='" + firstname  +
      " lastname='" + lastname +
      " personNbr='" + personNbr +
      " prio=" + prio +
      " number=" + number;
}
```

You need to `poll()` instead of just printing them. `poll()` retrieves and removes the head of this queue. That will represent the true ordering of the elements in the queue, not the `toString()`.

```
while (!pq.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println(pq.poll());
}
```

output:

```
firstname='Kalle lastname='Karlsson personNbr='8503622-1213 prio=3 number=1
firstname='Kallee lastname='Karlssonn personNbr='85503622-1213 prio=3 number=4
firstname='Lisa lastname='Svensson personNbr='840312-1224 prio=7 number=2
firstname='Lena lastname='Nilsson personNbr='820323-1224 prio=9 number=3
```

Analysis:

`Kalle` and `Kallee` have the highest priority (least value), but the `number` for `Kalle` is lower than `Kallee`. Others are organized by the `prio`.

Comment: thanks.. How the PriorityQueue knows that when code reach `return prio - rhs.prio;` so if it is 4-3=1 ===> so it is put in the first index of the PriorityQueue

Comment: No. The returned value does not determine the exact place in the queue. 
An unbounded priority queue based on a priority heap. The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time. Here `prio` is bigger than `rhs.prio` so `rhs.prio` will come first in queue. If you want it in other war round then negate the result.

Comment: what determines the exact place in the queue? is there in the code that determines it ? thanks

Comment: You can find more information about java [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) in the link.

Comment: one more question : in the code uses this ; `if(prio==rhs.prio) { }` How the code knows that the value of `rhs.prio` is not same like `rhs` ... I mean that we do not use for example `rhs.prio.next` !! thanks

Comment: Sorry. I did not understand what you are trying to ask here?

Comment: please look at the code in my post .. You will see my code's output .. the output is not totally correct because prio 7 is after prio 9 .. So what is the wrong with the code ..thanks

Comment: check now. You need to poll() element. Not print them.

Answer (score 0):

The `conmpareTo` method is defining an ordering such that the `prio` field is sorted first, then the `number` field. If the `prio` fields are equal then the difference is derived from the `number` field. If `prio` is not equal then it is the `prio` field that is compared.

The `equals` method states that two objects are equal if `compareTo` returns zero - which makes sense if you think about it.

Comment: thanks.. How the PriorityQueue knows that when code reach `return prio - rhs.prio;` so if it is 4-3=1 ===> so it is put in the first index of the PriorityQueue